# Is this game shirk or not?

Tags: practical-islam, sharia

So one month ago I pleaded a game call Dream League Soccer which is a soccer/football game and when the player comes to the field he touches the ground before coming into the field but it is not me who did it but it is automatically so if I play the game with that player will that be shirk

Answer (score -1):

salaam,
I don't think you should worry. It is just a game and like you said, it has nothing to do with you. As long as you are not committing shirk, you're fine. Allah (swt) made Islam easy and Allah (swt) is also the most merciful. The fact that you are questioning it shows your firmness in faith. :) Hope that helps!
Michelle

Comment: Thank you so much Michelle for this answer